# Лестница - этимология

Tags: этимология

Верно ли, что "лестница" связана со словом "лезть", "лезу"?

Фасмер это подтверждает, но объяснения дает весьма путанные. 
К тому же не совсем понятен переход С<З в корне.

Comment: А каких объяснений вам надобно?!

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, да, словари сходятся в этом мнении.

*Лѣзти ~ *лѣзтва (>*лѣства)* как *брить ~ бритва*. Далее с суффиксом -иц(а) **лѣствица* (ср. ст.-сл. *лѣствица*). По аналогии со словами типа *звонница, темница* в > н.

[z] перешел в [s] вследствие ассимиляции по глухости – звонкости. Ср. в современном русском ле[z]у ~ ле[s']ть.